# SQL/PLSQL merge multilist value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table name table1 and table2.

[image]

from first table I'm getting number,id and value.ID column is multilist so values in that column are separated by comma, eg: 3799952,3799953. For each ID there is some value in table2. eg for 3799952 value is Assembly and for 3799953 value is Indiviual. I have to get these values with comma separation. in multilist as of now I have only two value so I used sequence upto 2, tomorrow I will be getting multiple value . can anyone help me procedures or userdefined function.

```
select id,item_number,max(decode(seq,1,entry_id))||','||max(decode(seq,2,entry_id)) entry_id,
  max(decode(seq,1,entryvalue))||','||max(decode(seq,2,entryvalue)) entryvalue
  from (

  select a.id,a.item_number,a.entry_id,list.entryvalue,row_number() over (partition by item_number order by entry_id) seq
  from  (SELECT i.id,i.item_number,
 trim(regexp_substr(i.product_lines, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) entry_id
  FROM item i,
     TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
     (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(i.product_lines, ','))AS sys.odciNumberList)) lines   ORDER BY i.id)a , listentry list where a.entry_id=list.entryid and a.entry_id is not null)
  group by id,item_number;
```

This is my query and output for this is given below,

```
**ID    ITEM_NUMBER ENTRY_ID             ENTRYVALUE**
6024065 P00008           3799953,            Individual,
6024607 U00024          3799952,3799953       Assembly,Individual
6024886 U00154      3799952,3799953       Assembly,Individual
6015685 INK_PEN         3799952,              Assembly,
6036877 P0000020    3799952,3799953       Assembly,Individual
```

As of now I have only two entryvalue so used `max(decode(seq,1,entry_id))||','||max(decode(seq,2,entry_id)) entry_id` could any one tell me how to modify this for multiple values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've formatted you code and output a bit, perhaps you could improve them further?

Comment: "*values in that column are separated by comma*" - **very**, very bad idea

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  that is multilist attribute so those are separated by comma. Can you pls help

Comment: @Tony Andrews  thanks

Comment: @Angela You can create separate table to hold entry_id and entry_value.

Comment: @Sabin Jose yes, I am getting it from two different tables one is item and second is from listentry.

Comment: What version of Oracle do you have?

Comment: @mathguy 11g am using

Comment: Is that 11.1 or 11.2? Post the full version, as reported by `select * from v$version`. The function `LISTAGG()`, which could be used here, was only introduced in 11.2. Generally, whenever you post, on this site or any other one like it, include your FULL version number.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear about what you are trying to achieve - however, it appears you have two comma-delimited lists that you want to separate so that the values remain correlated. You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause. Something like this (untested):

```
WITH data ( id, item_number, entity_id, entryvalue,
            entity_start, entity_end, entry_start, entry_end ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         item_number,
         entity_id,
         entryvalue, 
         1,
         INSTR( entity_id, ',', 1 ),
         1,
         INSTR( entryvalue, ',', 1 )
  FROM   your_table
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         item_number,
         entity_id,
         entryvalue, 
         entity_end + 1,
         INSTR( entity_id, ',', entity_end + 1 ),
         entry_end + 1,
         INSTR( entryvalue, ',', entry_end + 1 )
  FROM   data
  WHERE  entity_end > 0 AND entry_start > 0
)
SELECT id,
       item_number,
       CASE entity_end
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR( entity_id, entity_start )
         ELSE SUBSTR( entity_id, entity_start, entity_end - entity_start )
       END AS entity_id,
       CASE entry_end
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR( entryvalue, entry_start )
         ELSE SUBSTR( entryvalue, entry_start, entry_end - entry_start )
       END AS entryvalue
FROM   data;
```

Comment: firstly my table1 is having values with comma like a,b,c . in another table there is a value for a ,b and c . so firstly I have sperated it to get particular values and after getting values I have to again combine it with comma. at present my list is having only 2 values to I used "max(decode(seq,1,entry_id))||','||max(decode(seq,2,entry_id)) entry_id"  upto seq 2. but my requirement my query should have capacity to combine any no of values dynamically. I'm new to SQL trying hard to find out but not able to.

Comment: @Angela then please clarify your question with a [MCVE] including the DDL/DML statements for your tables and some example data illustrating the problem and what you expect the output to be (and a clear written explanation of why that result is expected and the logic to get there). I can continue guessing what your requirements are but it would be much better to edit your question and make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `listagg()` twice:

```
select id, item_number, 
       listagg(entry_id, ',') within group (order by seq) entry_id,
       listagg(entryvalue, ',') within group (order by seq) entryvalue
  from your_inner_query
  group by id, item_number
```

---

test data:

```
create table item (id number(8), item_number varchar2(10), product_lines varchar2(20));
insert into item values (6024065, 'P00008',   '3799953,');
insert into item values (6024607, 'U00024',   '3799952,3799953,');
insert into item values (6024886, 'U00154',   '3799952,3799953,');
insert into item values (6015685, 'INK_PEN',  '3799952,');
insert into item values (6036877, 'P0000020', '3799952,3799953,');

create table listentry(entryid number(8), entryvalue varchar2(10));
insert into listentry values (3799952, 'Assembly');
insert into listentry values (3799953, 'Individual');
```

full query:

```
with t as (
    select a.id, a.item_number, a.entry_id, list.entryvalue,
                row_number() over (partition by item_number order by entry_id) seq
      from (select i.id,i.item_number,
                   trim(regexp_substr(i.product_lines, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) entry_id
              from item i,
                   table (cast (multiset ( select level 
                                             from dual 
                                             connect by level <= regexp_count(i.product_lines, ',')) 
                            as sys.odcinumberlist)) lines   
              order by i.id) a
           join listentry list on a.entry_id = list.entryid and a.entry_id is not null )
select id, item_number, 
       listagg(entry_id, ',') within group (order by seq) entry_id,
       listagg(entryvalue, ',') within group (order by seq) entryvalue
  from t
  group by id, item_number
  order by id;
```

output:

```
       ID ITEM_NUMBER ENTRY_ID           ENTRYVALUE
--------- ----------- ------------------ ----------------------
  6015685 INK_PEN     3799952            Assembly
  6024065 P00008      3799953            Individual
  6024607 U00024      3799952,3799953    Assembly,Individual
  6024886 U00154      3799952,3799953    Assembly,Individual
  6036877 P0000020    3799952,3799953    Assembly,Individual
```

---

---

**Edit: explanation**

Subquery `a` divides data in table `item` into individual rows. Hierarchical query `connect by` generates as many rows as needed for each `id` counting commas `,` in `product_lines`.
Function `regexp_substr` cuts off needed `entry_id` into separate rows.

```
ID       ITEM_NUMBER   ENTRY_ID
-------  ------------  --------
6015685  INK_PEN        3799952
6024065  P00008         3799953
6024607  U00024         3799952
6024607  U00024         3799953
6024886  U00154         3799953
6024886  U00154         3799952
6036877  P0000020       3799952
6036877  P0000020       3799953
```

Such table is next joined with your lookup table `listentry`. Each row is numbered with `row_number()`. So we have this:

```
ID       ITEM_NUMBER   ENTRY_ID  ENTRYVALUE   SEQ
-------  ------------  --------  -----------  ---
6015685  INK_PEN        3799952  Assembly       1
6036877  P0000020       3799952  Assembly       1
6036877  P0000020       3799953  Individual     2
6024065  P00008         3799953  Individual     1
6024607  U00024         3799952  Assembly       1
6024607  U00024         3799953  Individual     2
6024886  U00154         3799952  Assembly       1
6024886  U00154         3799953  Individual     2
```

Now we can use `listagg()` which groups data for the same id. They are sorted by `SEQ`.

Note that I didn't change your original inner query, only added last `select` with `listagg()` instead of `decode`'s You tried.

Comment: The OP said the first comma-separated list is given. The second comma-separated list must be created based on the first list and the lookup table. Separate from that, let's see what sub-version of Oracle the OP uses; she said 11g, which is not enough info. LISTAGG exists in 11.2 but it does not exist in 11.1.

Comment: Yes, You are right, we can use original values from `item.product_lines`.

Comment: @mathguy yes, I'm using 11.2 , it supports LISTAGG function . I will check the query you shared and will update you. Thanks a lot for ur great help :)

Comment: @mathguy hurray it worked fine , really really thanks. If possible can you brief description of that query pls.

Comment: @Angela - description of your original query added at the bottom.

Comment: Hi @Mathguy I need one more help on same Query shared by you. the query you shared is working as expected, but my another query is when In item table we have 5 columns id (which is unique), item_number,entry_id,product_lines, description when I do ""select * from Item (including some replace query in select)"" in place of 'product_lines' -> 'entry_value' must be replaced .  we get 'Entry_value' value from the above query you shared. do I also need to use replace function with select * statement ?   Please can you help me on this.

Comment: Hi @Angela. If any of our answers worked for you then please mark it as accepted. If you have new question please write it as new topic. We should not add new questions and answers in one thread even if they are correlated. This is not how Stack Overflow is organized. Please start new question, try to explain all details and be as specific as possible. This way you have better chance for correct answer from different users.

Comment: @PonderStibbons sure I will close this. Thanks for help